# Is there a driver/browser that support Widevine drm in headless mode?

Tags: browser-automation

Recently for a Project. I am looking for a driver/browser that can play widevide DRM content in headless mode.

I have already tried chrome driver but it doesn't support Widevine content.

Comment: Any luck on this matter? I am trying to run Netflix player using chrome driver in headless mode but I am getting the following screenshot: " Pardon the interruption please visit chrome://settings/content/protectedContent and make sure "Sites can play protected content" is selected."